# Using pspell to determine if a word is a noun or not

Tags: php, string, dictionary, grammar, pspell

Is it possible to use pspell to determine if a word is a noun or not? If not, is there any other easier way? Thanks.

```
$word = "cat";
$pspell_link = pspell_new("en"); //spell check
$boo = pspell_check($pspell_link, $word); //check the word
```

Comment: PSpell knows nothing about words outside of their spelling as per the loaded dictionary -- so no, it can't help you determine whether a word is a noun or not. I don't know of a way to do so, though.

Comment: How do you want to handle words like `jump` or `run`, which are both noun *and* verb? Or `fast`, which can be noun, verb and adjective?

Comment: Well, I guess I can't handle those words. I would just use them as a noun then, if it can be a noun and something else. Not like I have a choice, really. @paxdiablo

Comment: One method could be to use the Wordnet dictionary. It comes with a good list of nouns. You can match the word against lines in the data.noun or index.noun files.